# Bars chart for different number of bars in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, histogram, data-visualization

I want to create chart only using d3 library. My chart will have different number of vertical bars depending on data and x-axis for this. My question is how to set chart dynamically and set x-axis ticks under every bar. It will be better if width of bars will be constant.
I tried to use ranges and scale but i dont actually understand how they works. Even with some topics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "Grouped Bar Chart".

Refer this block from Mike Bostock.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Looks like want i need. Thank you!